# Is this update lost?

Tags: mysql, database, concurrency

I just want understand the meaning of "update lost" which is solved by transaction.

Please take a look at following two transaction, I use mysql 5.5.8 and innodb storage engine:

```
create table counter (what varchar(5), id integer, count integer, primary key (id));
insert into counter values ('total', 0, 0);

      session 1 (T1)                       session 2(T2)
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
0                               |           begin;
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           begin;              |        
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
2   select count from  counter  |
    where id = 0;               |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
3                               |   update counter set count = 50 
                                |   where id = 0; 
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
4                               |   commit;
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
5  update counter set count     |
   = 1000 where id = 0;         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
6           commit;             |        
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

you can consider value 1000 and 50 as this:

1. The update value 1000 depends on the read of count, i.e. select.
2. The update value 50 depends on another read(isn't conflict with session1).

So, this is the typical read-write-write dependency.

After **session1 (T1)** commit and execute 'select count from counter where id=0' again, the count will be 1000. I am wondering whether it is **update lost** or not? if not why? If I remembered correctly any kind of update last will be avoided in any isolation level.

One of possible fix is using "select count from counter where id = 0 for update;" at step 2, that's equivalent to add xlock on the record, and hence T2 will be blocked. So this is serial executed as **[T1,T2]**.

Is this the (known) bug of Innodb? Note, this isn't equivalent to execute **[T2,T1]**, because, T1 will read 50 other 0 with this sequence, and the final result will be different.

Thanks

Comment: You need to describe your actual task so we can give you sample scenario how to solve it.

Comment: @zerkms, I just want to understand what is the meaning of "update lost".

Comment: Between Session2-commit and Session1-commit, count will be value 50, but after Session1-commit, it will be **like the update to 50 never took place**. So we can call the update  lost'.

Comment: I think it is update lost, from what i find, in this case(select * from ..), innodb will perform non-locking read. we at least add a shared lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ofcourse the update is lost. To the outside world, your transaction only really "executes" when it commits. To a third party, your schema corresponds to:

1. Session 2 updates counter to 50 for ID 0
2. Session 1 updates counter to 1000 for ID 0

You don't actually even need transactions for this: the transactions make no difference. They would matter if your session 1 did its select AFTER session 2 did its update. In that case, with transactions, Session 1 will read value 0, but without transactions it would read value 50.

Comment: I just do not know how to use mysql shell for programming, you could think the updated value(50 and 1000) depends on the what the value of count is.

Comment: @Chang what, and why do you need to program in the mysql shell ? Note, that for transactions you could prevent the lost update here by issuing `select count from  counter where id = 0 for update;` Then again, things like this are often time dependant, and you have little control over which transaction is going to hit the DB first

Comment: @nos, I need't program in my-sql shell, actually, what i want to say is 1000 and 50 is calculated from count. By the way, I updated  my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the INNODB default isolation level [REPEATABLE READ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read)

Answer (score 0):

yes,your scenario is exactly what lost update means. in postgresql,T1 will be aborted by the dbms to prevent lost update.